# try and except is not catching error in min max function - python

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

The program is designed to accept input from user and the minimum and maximum values are then printed out. This works fine, until the try and except is tested.

Code snippet:

```
min = None
max = None
#wrap entire function in while loop
while True:
    #prompt user for input
    line = input('Enter a number: ')
    try:
        if line == 'done':
            break
        print(line)
        #min and max
        if min is None or line < min:
            min = line
            print("min:",min)
        if max is None or line > max:
            max = line
            print("max:",max)

    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
#print function results
print(min,max)
```

when string value is added as input i.e abcd

- the output is: min abc , max abc
- the expected output is: "Invalid Input"

Comment: The solution that worked was adding the code:

```line = int(line)
```
above the min and max conditionals. The input from the user is converted into an integer and if it is not an integer then try and except executes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are always comparing your inputs as strings.

For example, the user inputs "8", and then you store the string "8" in min and max. Then the user inputs "abcd" and you check if "abcd" < "8". This is a perfectly valid comparison because < is defined for comparing two strings.

If you want to only compare numbers, you should convert each input to a number before doing any comparisons:

```py
min = None
max = None
#wrap entire function in while loop
while True:
    #prompt user for input
    line = input('Enter a number: ')
    try:
        if line == 'done':
            break
        print(line)
        #min and max
        line = int(line)
        if min is None or line < min:
            min = line
            print("min:",min)
        if max is None or line > max:
            max = line
            print("max:",max)

    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
#print function results
print(min,max)
```